# Prevent Spring from prefixing booleans with is only in certain cases

Tags: java, spring, boolean, lombok

I have an object with a `boolean` property called `hasEnoughBalance`, but Spring (or Lombok, or whoever it is) appears to be renaming the getter to `isHasEnoughBalance` instead of `getHasEnoughBalance` or plain `hasEnoughBalance`. How could I prevent that?

I know of `@JsonProperty`, but I'd like another solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being done by Lombok. One way is to use wrapper **Boolean** in place of primitive **boolean**. For primitives, Lombok generates getter appended with **is** but for wrapper classes, it uses **get**.

Comment: Ok. So I guess we must live with an awful `isHasEnoughBalance` as getter... meh

Answer (score 2):

To disable `is` prexfixes, you can use `lombok.getter.noIsPrefix=true`. You could also use `@Accessors(fluent = true)`.

See [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) and [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) for more info.

(as a side note, `is` is the conventional prefix for boolean getters. Should you decide to skip it, you might break functionality that depends on Java bean conventions. You have been warned)